# How to make excel auto-detect are using what is add-in?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-addins

I write an add-in *.xlam for excel workbook. I have tested it on my computer, it's ok! But when I copy the file onto another computer, the formula in the cells behave weirdly - they are  prefixed by **"C://path/test.xlam"! |the original formula|** automatically by Excel.

How to make Excel NOT change my formulas like that?

Comment: Did you copy your Add-In on the other computer as well? If you don't want to copy your Add-In on the other computer, you should keep only the values returned by your user-defined functions in your Excel worksheet, not the formulas (copy the cells / paste the values).

Comment: i have copied addin, opened excel options/ Add-ins/ Manage Add-ins/ remove test.xlam and then add new. But excel file still take path old addin in formular field. i have to manual replace... so bored!

Comment: Maybe you have opened the worksheet before installing the Add-In on the other computer? Try saving the worksheet again from your computer (where it's OK), and open it on the other computer after the Add-In is installed.

Comment: @Davuz I think the best way to get the formula unchanged for the moment is to import the addin which has the SAME path on both computers - this is such an annoying thing Microsoft made in Excel to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should copy the addin into `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\AddIns` on both computers - this shall make your formulas to have the same path and Excel will stop its funny `prefixing` job